# How to validate password input without using javascript?

Tags: html, passwords

is there a way to validate passwords without using JavaScript, only html?
What i have in mind is that user input should have 8 characters atleast, it should contain number and also "uppercase and lowercase"

`<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">`

Answer (score 0):

you can use pattern for validation and title for a title to show user what to use.

```
<input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters">
```

learn more at : [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern)